# Grouping and Sorting in R

Tags: r

I am an Excel user attempting to transition some of my routine data reporting tasks to R. One of the most powerful features in Excel is the ability to pivot and sort data. I know these functions are features in R as well but I am not sure how to write the code to solve this particular grouping and sorting problem.

Basically, using R I would like to take a data set that looks like this:

[image: Simple Data Set]

And transform it to look like this:

[image: Pivoted Data Set]

Notice that the final table groups points by team and then sorts the summary data by the number of points scored. Learning how to do this in R would be a huge time saver.

Thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: SO is not a "gimme the codez" site. Attempt something and come back with a question on what you've written.

Comment: Aside from other comments (which I agree with), that's a really horrible format for the final table...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two functions you will need ... once you have an example ... are `xtabs` and `ftable`. First we convert an existing table to a dataframe and then note that the counts are now in a variable named "Freq". Then we re-tabulate to a smaller number of dimensions:

```
> Tdf <- as.data.frame(Titanic, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> str(Tdf)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Class   : chr  "1st" "2nd" "3rd" "Crew" ...
 $ Sex     : chr  "Male" "Male" "Male" "Male" ...
 $ Age     : chr  "Child" "Child" "Child" "Child" ...
 $ Survived: chr  "No" "No" "No" "No" ...
 $ Freq    : num  0 0 35 0 0 0 17 0 118 154 ...

> ftable( xtabs(Freq ~ Class+Sex, Tdf) , row.vars=c("Class", "Sex") )
Class Sex        
1st   Female  145
      Male    180
2nd   Female  106
      Male    179
3rd   Female  196
      Male    510
Crew  Female   23
      Male    862
```

I haven't gotten very many points for it but I did at one time demonstrate on SO how to do sub-totals and grand totals:

[R: calculating column sums & row sums as an aggregation from a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982546/r-calculating-column-sums-row-sums-as-an-aggregation-from-a-dataframe/5982943#5982943)

Answer (score 2):

First, welcome to R and SO.  You'll find that you get better answers if you follow the guidelines here for posting questions:

[How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

You can accomplish what you are asking for in a number of ways.

First, you need to use the `sum` function over each grouping created by `c(Team,Player)`.  There are several ways of doing this:

- `by` in base R, plus `as.data.frame.by` in the `taRifx` package
- `ddply` in the `plyr` package

Then take the resulting output and sort it (again, lots of ways to do that):

- `sort` in the `taRifx` package
- `arrange` in the `plyr` package

Since it sounds like you'll be doing this a lot, I'd strongly suggest creating your own function which performs the two steps in just the way you'd like automatically.  You can then put that function in your `.Rprofile` or in a package so it's always available.